# Certain things displaying with odd colours

Tags: windows-7, images

Sorry I couldn't be more specific with the title...

Anyway, iTunes looks like this:

[image: iTunes]

...and Windows Photo Viewer looks like this:

[image: Dog]

I haven't seen the problem anywhere else, and I have no idea what's causing it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can't be a monitor issue (since you can copy and paste and we can see the green).

> Click Start, type `Color Management` and select Colour Management.
>   In the Color Management dialog box, click to select the Use my
>   settings for this device check box.
>   In the Profiles associated with
>   this device list, click the color profile that you want to remove, and
>   then click Remove.
>   Note If you receive a warning message, click Yes.
>   Click Close to close the Color Management dialog box.
>    Restart the computer.
>   [Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-live-photo-gallery-green-background/1d0f76ce-cac4-45a1-95cf-c24d148f83c8)

If that fails, I suggest you update the drivers for your graphics card/device. Some times the chipset drivers can help as they bundle all sorts of goodies in there.